# Fail to complete Android Espresso JUnitTest

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, android-espresso

i'm trying to create an ui-test in my app but with no luck.
every time i get the error:

> android.support.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?

here is my test code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class UITestApp {

    @ClassRule
    public static final LocaleTestRule localeTestRule = new LocaleTestRule();


    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<SplashActivity> mainActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);


    @Test
    public void testMainActivity(){

        onView(withId(R.id.imageView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        Screengrab.screenshot("screenshot");

    }
}
```

i am running my test on emulator, and the gradle.build seems to be okay.

Answer (score 1):

The trace says it all - you need to getActivity.
Try adding this to the code:

```
private SplashActivity splashActivity;
@Before
public void setActivity() {
       splashActivity = mainActivityTestRule.getActivity();
}
```